# how to make a key unique in dynamodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have to make a key unique in dynamo db. i want to make my email unique, if the email is already existed in database then when i enter next time the same email id then it should not enter to database. it should give a response "email already exists". How can i get that?

This is the response which i am getting an employee..in this example i dont need to insert another email value like hari@gmail.com

```
{
            "defaultEmp": 0,
            "empName": "Hari",
            "statuses": 1,
            "designation": "store keeper",
            "id": 1,
            "storeId": 1,
            "email": "hari@gmail.com"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose accordingly, what you want to achieve [partition key vs composite key](https://vitalflux.com/dynamodb-partition-key-composite-partition-key/).

1: you can use the designation as a partition key and email as a sort key [Using sort key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-sort-keys-to-organize-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/).

- If you want to get all of the email related to single designation this 
   scenario is great.
- But make sure your design wont end up hitting the only designation otherwise 
   it will end up throttling issue [Provision throughput must be divide evenly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html).

2: you can use the email as a Partition key and designation as a Sort key or only 
   email as Partition key.

- For a single email what are the designation available

3: simply select email as Partition key.

NOTE:

-make sure email and designation composite Primary key are unique else it will overwrite data.

-This is my first contribution :) Correct me if I am wrong and feel free to give any suggestion.
Thanks!

Comment: Note: option 3 is the only one where DynamoDb will enforce the unique email requirement.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to make an ID for email to make it unique.. just check the email exists on the db when a user creates an account.. just like that.. no need to make additional field and check it.